# How does dir="auto" affect the tooltip created with title="example"?

Tags: html, right-to-left

If I create an HTML element with a tooltip, how does `dir="auto"` affect it? Is there a way to set the `dir` property of just the tooltip?

For example:

```html
<div dir="ltr">
  <a
    href="#"
    title="1 اثنين 3"
  >abc</a>
  <br>
  <a
    dir="auto"
    href="#"
    title="1 اثنين 3"
  >abc</a>
  <br>
  <a
    href="#"
    title="1 اثنين 3"
    >عربية</a>
  <br>
  <a
    dir="auto"
    href="#"
    title="1 اثنين 3"
    >عربية</a>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my brief testing, this is how `dir="auto"` works with tooltips:

The tooltip's direction is identical to the element's direction. If `dir="auto"`, the element's direction is set automatically based on the contents of the element, and not based on the `title` attribute. So if the element's content begins with RTL characters, then the direction will be set to RTL for both the content of the element and for the tooltip. Conversely, if the element's content begins with LTR characters, then the direction will be set to LTR for both the content of the element and for the tooltip.

You can see for yourself in the code snippet in the question post.

There is no way to set `dir="auto"` for just the tooltip. I wish that `dirtitle="auto"` existed, but it doesn't.